# Apply index configurations on index creation

Tags: elasticsearch, hibernate-search

I'm using hibernate-search-elasticsearch 5.11.5 and I hit an index limit- total fields limits which defaults to 1000. I need to increase this limit, which unfortunately is an index limit, which means that it must be set after the index created. Because I have more than 1000 fields,
an error occurred when the mappings are created. The problem is that the request that creates the index mappings is executed after the index creation and I can't see a way to apply index settings before the mapping creation. Here is the code from ElasticsearchIndexManager class that handles index and mappings creation:

```
 case DROP_AND_CREATE:
 case DROP_AND_CREATE_AND_DROP:
        ElasticsearchSchemaDropper schemaDropper = elasticsearchService.getSchemaDropper();
            schemaDropper.dropIfExisting( actualIndexName, schemaManagementExecutionOptions );
            schemaCreator.createIndex( indexMetadata, schemaManagementExecutionOptions );
            schemaCreator.createMappings( indexMetadata, schemaManagementExecutionOptions );
            createdIndex = true;
            break;
```

Is there any possibility of applying index settings after the index creation. And if not what will you recommend apart from reducing the fields(I know what are the risks with so many fields)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create index templates beforehand: you define templates with the appropriate settings before the indexes are created, and Elasticsearch will apply these settings automatically when Hibernate Search creates the indexes.

See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/indices-templates.html

Note Hibernate Search 5 will still create indexes on startup, so you will need to create these templates by sending REST requests to the cluster yourself, before starting the application, using a shell script and `curl`, for example.